# Почему возникает данная ошибка при работе c RouterOS?

Tags: mikrotik

Почему данный скрипт:

```
:global ifLTE "lte1";
:global ifWAN "WAN";
:global status do={
    /ip dhcp-client get [find /ip dhcp-clent interface=$ifWAN] status
  }
:put $status;
```

Возвращает:

```
;(eval / (eval /ip dhcp-client getnumber=(eval (eval /ip dhcp-client findwhere=$interface;$add-default-route;$default-route-distance;$use-peer-dns;$use-peer-ntp;$dhcp-option
s;$script;$status;$address;$netmask;$gateway;$dhcp-server;$primary-dns;$secondary-dns;$primary-ntp;$secondary-ntp;$caps-managers;$expires-after;$invalid;$dynamic;$disabled;$
comment;$.id;$.nextid;$.dead;(  $/ip (- $dhcp $clent) (= $interface $ifWAN));5));value-name=status))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает

```
:global ifWAN "e2-ft";
:global status [/ip dhcp-client get [find /ip dhcp-clent interface=$ifWAN] status];
:put $status;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но почему?

Comment: Видать потому что вы ожидаете возврат результата, а это дает команда /ip dhcp-client get. А do не возвращает результат а всего лишь выполняет блок команд если стоит вместе с while, if, for.

Comment: Слушай, а есть ли возможность использовать функции в ros?

Comment: говорят что теперь можно, но сам не пробовал -  https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Scripting#Functions